# RadioGroup in ExpandableList with checkboxes

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable list with checkboxes, however some childs have radio buttons instead of them. I need these radio buttons to act like a radio group. How can i do it?[image]

Comment: can you provide any code?

Comment: what exactly you need?

Comment: post your code or any image so i can understand what you want exactly

Comment: added an image @HetalUpadhyay

Comment: you can use different child views...check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286235/using-two-different-layouts-for-child-items-in-expandablelistview

Comment: you can uncheck other radiobuttons in code on click of one. or why not use radiogroup with some extra logic to merge items for radiobuttons?

Comment: @MohammadhussainKhatri i don't know, how to use radio group there... the problem is that i have only one radiobutton in XML file, for every row, i can't unchek on other rows

Comment: `i can't unchek on other rows` ? so what is the desired behaviour ?

Comment: i mean i tried to do that but didn't manage to